# Modify endcap .round style, to be more apparently round, unlike the example image shown here

Tags: ios, uikit, cashapelayer, swift5

I've just learned that the **standard** Apple `.round` endcap

```
let l = CAShapeLayer()
l.path = .. just a straight line, say 50 long
l.lineWidth =  say "3.1" in the example shown here
l.lineCap = .round
```

*is not very apparently round* in some cases, see images.

## If I want apparently "exact semi-circle" endcaps, what to do?

I appreciate that I could build my own line line and fill it.

But is there a way to perhaps subclass "endcap" in some way?

It would be magic if you could say `= .myHappyEndcapMode`

[image]

How do we fix this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can see how far off it is here:

[image]

Further info:

The non-round visual look appears to arise in the case of:

- Thin lines
- Possibly when the width is non-integer
- In the situation at hand I had gradients on gradients and fades everywhere, it may not help

Comment: Can you show an example of what you are getting, compared to how you want it to look? This is what I get, and it looks pretty round to me... https://imgur.com/a/RLo5w45

Comment: @Fattie Can you show us the code where you create the path (the line, as you say)? I have a feeling that you are calculating the line points and it is not a rounded number. Having a point at `(10.33, 8)` for example could make the line look not-so round.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to “subclass” the cap shape. You will have to manually construct the outline of the shape if you want a different cap shape.

The round cap is already exactly as circular as a circle created with `CGPath(ellipseIn:)`.

Here's a round-capped line drawn on top of a circle of slightly larger radius, zoomed 8x:

[image: zoomed image]

The curvature of the line cap starts exactly at the horizontal center of the circle.

Here's the code:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let lineWidth: CGFloat = 20
let circleRadius = lineWidth / 2 + 1

let lineLayer = CAShapeLayer()
lineLayer.position = .init(x: 30, y: 30)
let path = CGMutablePath()
path.move(to: .zero)
path.addLine(to: .init(x: 30, y: 0))
lineLayer.path = path
lineLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
lineLayer.lineCap = .round
lineLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
lineLayer.fillColor = nil

let circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
circleLayer.position = lineLayer.position
circleLayer.path = CGPath(ellipseIn: CGRect.zero.insetBy(dx: -circleRadius, dy: -circleRadius), transform: nil)
circleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor

let view = UIView(frame: .init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 80))
view.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
view.layer.addSublayer(circleLayer)
view.layer.addSublayer(lineLayer)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```

Comment: Thanks; hmm, I wonder if it renders a bit differently - I was using lines as a mask come to think.  Will investigate.

Comment: Notice my final edited example *"You can see how far off it is here:"*  @robmayoff

Comment: I don’t see the problem. It looks to me like the orange box contains a quarter of a disc, as it should.

Comment: The height of the butt (height is left-right in that image as pasted in) is less than the height of the box.

Comment: (In the other large image pasted in, which is a thin line, the perceptual problem is even worse; at first glance the ratio of what should be a quarter disc looks like 4 : 5.5 or so rather than square.

Answer (score 1):

I have to wonder if you are seeing something we are not...

Here is a line end, 8-pt width (which renders at 16-pixels on an iPhone 8), zoomed-in to 3200%

[image]

As you can see, the rounded end-cap has a radius of *exactly* 8-pixels.

And here is the actual screen-cap I used to get the above zoomed-in image. The line-widths go from 1 to 10:

[image]

---

**EDIT**

Hmmm... seems like either **A)** It's optical, and you're not counting all the anti-aliased pixels in your enlarged images (that is, while the end-cap *is* round, it just doesn't *look* round to you), or **B)** Maybe you're scaling / stretching your image / layers?

Here are a couple more example images - this time, I'm using the `CAShapeLayer` as a mask on a `CAGradientLayer` overlaid on a `UIImageView`:

[image]

[image]

Screen cap used for those enlarged images:

[image]

And the source to generate that view, if you want to play around with it:

```
class GradientView: UIView {

    override open class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAGradientLayer.classForCoder()
    }

    lazy var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = {
        return self.layer as! CAGradientLayer
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() -> Void {

        if let l = layer as? CAGradientLayer {
            let c1 = UIColor(rgb: 0x6119D2)
            let c2 = UIColor(rgb: 0x7E1CC6)

            l.colors = [c1.cgColor, c2.cgColor]
            l.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
            l.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)
        }

    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        let l = CAShapeLayer()
        let bez = UIBezierPath()
        let xOffset = bounds.size.height * 0.5 + 4
        bez.move(to: CGPoint(x: xOffset, y: bounds.size.height * 0.5))
        bez.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.size.width - xOffset, y: bounds.size.height * 0.5))
        l.lineCap = .round
        l.lineWidth = bounds.size.height
        l.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        l.path = bez.cgPath

        self.layer.mask = l

    }
}

class EndCapViewController: UIViewController {

    let gView: GradientView = {
        let v = GradientView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    let imgView: UIImageView = {
        let v = UIImageView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let img = UIImage(named: "clouds") {
            imgView.image = img
        }

        view.addSubview(imgView)
        view.addSubview(gView)

        let lineThickness: CGFloat = 8.0

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            imgView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            imgView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            imgView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 128.0),
            imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0),

            gView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0),
            gView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: lineThickness),
            gView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.centerXAnchor),
            gView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.centerYAnchor),

        ])

    }

}

extension UIColor {
    convenience init(red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int) {
        assert(red >= 0 && red <= 255, "Invalid red component")
        assert(green >= 0 && green <= 255, "Invalid green component")
        assert(blue >= 0 && blue <= 255, "Invalid blue component")

        self.init(red: CGFloat(red) / 255.0, green: CGFloat(green) / 255.0, blue: CGFloat(blue) / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    }

    convenience init(rgb: Int) {
        self.init(
            red: (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF,
            green: (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF,
            blue: rgb & 0xFF
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: DonMag, thanks, notice the two large images I posted, it is clear. You can see they are not even close to being a semi-circle.  I think I know the resolution here:  I was making a  >> mask << with the paths, and indeed, I was putting that on a gradient.  And indeed - all of that is on a background that has subtle swirly clouds.  Notice that in the examples of both yourself and robM it is drawing solid lines on white.  One of those three factors ("its a mask", ".. of a gradient", ".. mixed in to a background") would seem to be causing the behavior, that dithering style.

Comment: {Interesting random comment.  In your excellent example.  to my eye, 7 and 5 look flattened.  maybe it has trouble w/ half pixels anyways.}

Comment: awesome @DonMag .. notice in my first (of two) large images in the question; the line width was 3.1.  Yes, as you say "A) It's optical, and you're not counting all the anti-aliased pixels in your enlarged images (that is, while the end-cap is round, it just doesn't look round to you [ / anyone] )"  indeed looking at that image, notice the many rows of (very) soft pixels along the sids of the line (up and down in that image).  I feel the dithering algo. is just poor in the case of, perhaps (a) think lines, (b) non-integer lines, perhaps (c) something else I've did I missed.

Comment: @Fattie - as I'm sure you're aware, there is much more to **design** than simply saying "I want to do *this*." Trying to draw partial pixels is not necessarily "poor dithering algo". Way back, we had an app that had a "column" of labels. On every other row, the text looked "fuzzy." We figured out that or layout was trying to put the text on half-pixels, which resulted in - obviously - different anti-aliasing. Once we restricted the text to whole pixel positions, crisp clean text again. That may be something you need to examine with your layout.

Comment: absolutely, there are no absolute, platonic, 'right or wrong' dithering algorithms. If you look at my fist large image, it just clearly and obviously "does not look round", it looks flattened. (100% of people who look at the lines in question on a device, say "they look flattened not round".)  Anti-aliasing math for things like very shallow ilnes and other problematic cases, is tough.  For this very reason one makes choices betwen - say bilinear and trilinear filtering for images, depending on the use case,

Comment: .. you (and RobM) have absolutely resolved there's no "bug" or literal error or problem (certainly for whole-number widths).  So it's just an unfortunate anti-aliasing case.  (Much as you say, for example as an everyday example you often "just can't have" very shallow angles - no matter how much the design team wants that! :) )